# Matlab Matrix indexing with both column and row

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a 2 by 5 matrix:

```
d1=  3     3     1     1     2
     4     4     2     3     4
```

and there is a 4 by 5 zero matrix :

```
z1=  0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Each column of d1 shows the positions of 1's in the corresponding column in z1. Specifically, I want to get a result like:

```
r1=  0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     1
     1     1     0     1     0
     1     1     0     0     1
```

I am looking for an efficient way to obtain r1 from d1 and z1.

Comment: I don't get how you obtained the third matrix. Also, please read [ask], as Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please [edit] the question with the code you tried yourself, which is a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `d1` to linear indices, and use them to index `z1`:

```
% Prior to R2016b:
I = bsxfun(@plus, d1, (0:size(d1,2)-1) * size(z1,1));

% On or after R2016b:
I = d1 + (0:size(d1,2)-1) * size(z1,1));

% Index using the linearized indices
z1(I) = 1
```

Comment: Works like a charm! appreciate it

Comment: Nice avoiding `sub2ind`